# Mock OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

I have WCF service that I am trying to Unit Tests. The only dependency the service has is the call to OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name to know the windows user that uses that service (windows authentication) I want to mock only this.
Someone has simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your service is configured, Thread.CurrentPrincipal will likely contain a principal representing the connected client.  So you could get the name from that rather than having a dependency on OperationContext.

Comment: wow really thank you!!! very good answer because in my service I have the credentials and I can mock the current principal in my Unit Tests!